# How to call base/super class implementation (super.SomeMethod()) when implementing informal protocol using the ExportAttribute

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have the following reference swift code and I'm trying to implement the same thing in xamain.mac.

```
class MyTableView : NSTableView {
    override func cancelOperation(_ sender: Any?) {
        // some custom processing goes here
        super.cancelOperation(sender)        
        // another part of custom processing goes here
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the C# the `NSTableView` does not implement [`cancelOperation:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstandardkeybindingresponding/3005196-canceloperation?language=objc), so there is nothing to override.

I was able to handle the message with the direct export inside my `NSTableView` subclass:

```
[Export("cancelOperation:")]
private void CancelOperation(NSObject? sender)
{
    // some custom processing
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Custom processing");
    
    //won't compile
    //base.CancelOperation(sender);
    
    //crashes the app
    objc_msgSendSuper(this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle("cancelOperation:"),
                                        sender?.Handle ?? NativeHandle.Zero);
    
    //another part of custom processing
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("another part of custom processing");
}

[DllImport ("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib", EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
private static extern void objc_msgSendSuper(NativeHandle superReceiver, 
                                             NativeHandle selector,
                                             NativeHandle value);
```

And then the problem is that I can't call `base/super` implementation as a Swift code does. I can't just write `base.CancelOperation(sender)` because of this is not an overridden member, but a direct export.

As a workaround I tried to use `objc_msgSendSuper`, but this crashes the application (most likely because I'm doing it wrong).

So, the question is - how to implement the custom handler for the `cancelOperation:` (or other member of informal protocol) and call the `base/super` implementation from such a handler.

Test project which demonstrates the problem may be downloaded [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/files/12587482/cancelOperationTest.zip). Just enter something into the second column of the table then press Esc. This will cause a crash due to the `objc_msgSendSuper` inside the `MyNSTableView.CancelOperation` handler.

Comment: The issue is that NSTableView or any of the parent classes do not officially define this method. According to docs the only view class that officially conforms to NSStandardKeyBindingResponding is NSTextView

Comment: The `NSStandardKeyBindingResponding` protocol, of which the `cancelOperation:` is a part, belongs to the so-called "Action Messages" (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/action_messages?language=objc), which can be implemented by any object that can be a first responder. So, although `NSTableView` does not formally declare the conformance to such a protocol, it does implement at least some of the protocol members, which is confirmed by working Swift code.

Comment: So, I understood, why there is no direct inheritance of such members in the Xamarin (because of the apple headers does not show such a inheritance). But I still wonder to know the way how I can forward such a message of the informal protocol to the `base/super` implementation in Xamarin as it is done in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. The approach from the question was correct, and the problem was in the stupid mistake in the `objc_msgSendSuper` declaration - the functinon name is correct, but `EntryPoint` is wrong! The correct `EntryPoint` is `objc_msgSendSuper`.

So after replacing declaration with the following all works as expected:

```
[DllImport ("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib", EntryPoint = "objc_msgSendSuper")]
private static extern void objc_msgSendSuper(NativeHandle superReceiver, NativeHandle selector, NativeHandle value);
```